# Git bash change into a directory and start a file

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash

My default git bash starts on the `C: drive` and I often have to change into a project directory and start a file up.
Is there a way to `cd` into a directory and `start` a file all in one command using Git bash on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a file *.bashrc* into your home directory. It should be under
C:\Users\login

1. Add the following line in the file: `cd "projet_directory_full_path"`
2. Open a new session and it should start on your project directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly start with cat command following with complete path using forward slashes as 'cat C:/Users/username/filename' and cd command also works in similar way.